# Trying to add a line break in output file from a string

Tags: php, html, string, quotes

I have PHP saving an output file all from one very long string. I want this code that is being outputted to be formatted properly, so I am trying to add linebreaks in at certain points.. I have been trying to use `"\n"`, but for some reason that is not doing the trick.. Here's the  relevant code:

```
foreach($headerColumn as $hColumn) { 
    $outputString .= '<td>' . $hColumn . '</td>' . "\n";
};
```

Here I have the `"\n"` added to the end of the string, but for some reason it is being outputted like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Ticker</td><td>Buy Date</td><td>Current Yield</td>
</tr>
</thead>
```

When, in actuallity, I want each  on its' own line.. any ideas? in case it has something to do with the content type of the file, here is my file write call:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.txt"');
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); # Don't use application/force-download - it's not a real MIME type, and the Content-Disposition header is sufficient
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($outputString));
header('Connection: close');

echo $outputString;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just run through an HTML prettifier?

Comment: If I can, I would prefer to skip that step.. The purpose of what I am making is to simplify something we do often. I know that you can add line breaks into the source code, I am just unsure how to. but, thank you for the idea! @MikeBrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is `PHP_EOL`:

> PHP_EOL (string)
>   The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2

So, for your example:

```
$outputString .= '<td>' . $hColumn . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I see! Thank you.. (will accept answer in 1 minute when SO permits it.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best practice... but you can actually put a newline into the code by simply not ending the string quotation until the next line:

```
foreach($headerColumn as $hColumn) { 
    $outputString .= '<td>' . $hColumn . '</td>' . "
    ";
};
```

Comment: This works, but why did you get a down-vote? What would be the negative effect of doing this? (just trying to choose what's best.)

Comment: Vastly, I choose Dave's answer because it was the more official way of adding the line break... but thanks for your advice, take an up-vote!

Comment: No idea on the downvote. I have normally applied this for inserting a block of code with a single echo statement. Anyhow, thanks for the upvote.